# Counter no less than 0 using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my removeCountHandler I need to find out if the number is less than zero. If it is then keep it at zero

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const addCountHandler = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  const removeCountHandler = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  };

  return count <= 1  ? 
    <div>
        {count} person
      <Increment increment={addCountHandler} />
      <Decrement decrement={removeCountHandler} />
    </div>
  :
   <div>
        {count} persons
      <Increment increment={addCountHandler} />
      <Decrement decrement={removeCountHandler} />
    </div>
};
```

Comment: On the body of `removeCountHandler` you can try `if (count > 0) {setCount(count - 1);}`

Comment: Yeah just check for count==0 and make it a noop in that case. Also it'd be good if you control the count dropping beyond zero by disabling Decrement when count==0.

Comment: `  if (count <= 0) {
      setCount(0);
    } else {
      setCount(count - 1);
    }`
This worked

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the demo: 
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rjdebb)

Basically, you just check for the counter being zero in the removeCountHandler:

```js
function Counter(){
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const addCountHandler = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  const removeCountHandler = () => {
    if(count === 0){
      return;  
    }
    setCount(count - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        {count} person
      <button onClick={addCountHandler}>+</button>
      <button onClick={removeCountHandler}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```